# Is there a C/C++ IDE that wouldn't prompt to save before compiling?

Tags: c++, c, ide, save, read-eval-print-loop

Here's a common situation for me: I have this idea of a code in my head (in this example, it's in Python), so I open up PyScripter, write the code and then simply run it. PyScripter doesn't ask me to save the code beforehand and in a matter of seconds I happily glance at my algo's results.

Now I understand that C is a compiled language and the code must be saved beforehand, et cetera, et cetera, but I was wondering if there is such an IDE that let's you simply enjoy your code without having many saved files or folders named `"test1.*"`,`"test2.*"`, etc...

One way I guess this could be done is that the IDE will manage all project files in a temp folder, up until (and if at all...) the user clicks on "save/save as"; then it will actually save the files in a desired location. *So in most cases, where the user just wants to write a code and see its output, the IDE won't bother the user with save prompts.*

*I'd be very glad if someone could recommend me of such IDEs (if they even exist). A big thanks in advance =]*

edit: @Michael Burr Yes, the intention was indeed not to come up with filenames in the first place.

Comment: This would be one for me. I have a folder full of files named a, b, c, almost all the way to cz now.

Comment: Not a answer to your question but if you want this for C#, VB.NET, or F# [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) does exactly what you want.

Comment: better ask: how can you do it in emacs?

Comment: Isn't it a once-in-lifetime problem to set up a `quick_test` project in your favorite IDE, and then use that for any future tests? Worked fine for me.

Comment: The vast majority of IDE's use a separate compiler program, even if it's included in the same installation bundle, so they actually need to create a file to feed to the compiler.  An IDE could be made to create a temp file and substitute it into the build, but that's messy.  On larger projects, you'll often have a revision control system, so you can do whatever you want to a working tree and simply revert to the last checked in version if your experimental modification proves unproductive.

Comment: That's what I was going for (an IDE that uses temp files). I think that for small & quick sketches (unlike large projects) this type of environment would be great.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/). I find it very convenient :-)

It's online so no actual installation is required, and it supports a lot of known programming languages.

Answer (score 6):

For C++, you can do this in Visual Studio. Next time you modify a file, just press `F5`(Run) and when the prompt comes up (asking whether you want to save the file before compiling) just check the box that says `Don't ask again`.

For Java, Eclipse(maybe others) provides automatic compilation, but you still have to save the file. You just need to check `Build Automatically`.

Comment: I think the OP doesn't even want to come up with filenames or directory locations in the first place - he just wants to type (or paste) in some code and have the IDE figure out appropriate temporary filenames and go.  I think that would be a great IDE feature for C/C++ for dealing with quick-n-dirty tests and such.

Answer (score 5):

CodePad seems to be created for just this reason. Write your code, hit the button, watch it run. No fuss, and no saving hundreds of files.

http://codepad.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you use emacs:

```
   (defun my-emacs-command-save-compile ()
    "save and compile."
    (interactive)
    (save-buffer)
    (recompile))
```